# Can I raise a database in the cloud ?

Tags: database, cloud, database-cloning

I programming `software` for rental cars, I have a `database`, can I raise the `database` on the `cloud`?
After putting them in the `cloud` Can I modify them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could easily see a setup where you track your database files for changes on either Google drive or Dropbox, or another similar service.  You will then be able to modify the file from any computer on which you have access to either Dropbox or Google drive, much as you would modify it on your computer.

Comment: How do I change it? by Xammp  ?

Comment: How did you create it?  What language is it in?

Comment: Worked connection software, data base with Android. I want the database in the cloud mode.